# Why doesn't my GQL query return any results in my GAE App?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gql

I have mostly followed a tutorial about how to build a gustbook using GAE and Python. Now I only want to show the entries from a particular day, but the GQL query doesn't return anything (although there are entries from that day):

```
class Shout(db.Model):  
    message= db.StringProperty(required=True)  
    when = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)  
    who = db.StringProperty()  

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):  
    def get(self):  
        shouts = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Shout WHERE when=DATE('2010-11-05')")  
        # Return something without the WHERE clause
        values = {'shouts':shouts}  
        self.response.out.write(template.render('main.html',values))  

    def post(self):  
        self.response.out.write("posted")  
        shout = Shout(message=self.request.get("message"),who=self.request.get("who"))  
        shout.put()
```

This is my main.html:

```
<form method="post">
   <input type="text" name="who"></input>
   <input type="text" name="message"></input>
   <input type="submit" value="Send"> </input>  
</form>

{% for shout in shouts  %}
   <div>{{shout.message}} from {{shout.who}} on {{shout.when}}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be another way around this, but I think that because your `when` property is a datetime you would be better served with something like this:

```
shouts = db.GqlQuery("""SELECT * 
                          FROM Shout 
                         WHERE when >= DATE('2010-11-05')
                           AND when < DATE('2010-11-06')""")
```

Comment: +1.  Alternatively, you can add a DateProperty to your model, and then query that using an equality filter.  This would take up a little more space, but would be easier to query (equality vice two relational operators - especially important since you can only use a relational operator on one field).

Comment: Thanks, it's working now. Is it because of some "rounding" issue that I can't just use '='?

Comment: I tried getting `=` to work on some sample data. It seems impossible because DateTime properties are stored with microseconds; which aren't AFAICT supported in GQL.

Comment: @user67011 It's because the post time is stored as a datetime (that's what you specified), and your date is translated to midnight on that day as a datetime. Your query will return only results that were posted at exactly midnight, because those are the only results posted at that exact time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
shouts = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Shout WHERE when=DATE('2010-11-05')").fetch(5000)
```

While it is possible to use a Query object as an iterable, it is a better idea to explicitly fetch the rows and not depend on the `for` in your template to do the work. I suspect that it is not supported in that way.

EDIT:
Now that I look more closely at this, I suspect that the problem is that the field you are querying on is a DateTimeProperty, and by using the DATE operator, you are essentially saying that you want 2010-11-05 00:00:00, and there are no records with that exact date and time, so try this instead:

```
shouts = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Shout WHERE when >= DATETIME('2010-11-05 00:00:00') and when <= DATETIME('2010-11-05 23:59:59')")
```

Comment: Same problem as before. I suppose the fetch isn't necessary because it's not used in the sample apps (e.g. http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/source/browse/trunk/guestbook/index.html).

Comment: I agree that it is a better idea to fetch the rows explicitly - it is more efficient to retrieve them all at once (the iterator retrieves them in chunks, which causes extra roundtrips to the datastore).  However, there is no problem with having the template iterate over the query object - it works just as if you had iterated over it using a regular for loop.

Comment: I'm not trying to sound accusatory: I don't like to see downvotes when someone is clearly trying to be helpful. Thanks for your answer, Adam.

Comment: Oh well. I rushed to answer the question and didn't think it through. My bad.